# ValueError in rank method in pandas without more explanation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Dataframe like this :

```
     year   week           city  avg_rank
0    2016     52          Paris         1
1    2016     52 Gif-sur-Yvette         2
2    2016     52          Paris         1
3    2017      1          Paris         4
4    2016     52          Paris         3
5    2016     52          Paris         5
6    2016     52          Paris         2
```

But this code line :

```
df['real_index']=df.groupby(by=['year', 'week', 'city']).avg_rank.rank(method='first')
```

generates that stack trace :

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in rank(self, axis, method, numeric_only, na_option, ascending, pct)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
590                                                                 *args, **kwargs)
591                         except(AttributeError):
592                             raise ValueError
593
594             return wrapper

ValueError:
```

I have no `NaN` value in those columns of my DataFrame.

I am using `python2.7` along with `pandas 0.18.1` and `numpy 1.11.0`.

The shape of my DataFrame is consisting of about 9.000.000 rows and 15 columns.

What is more intriguing is that when I execute this code line in all subsets of my DataFrame (for each subset of 1.000.000 rows), I don't raise any `ValueError`.

Is that a known behavior that `pandas` does not manage well quite big DataFrame or did I miss something ?

Any help is welcome !

Comment: Hmm, this worked fine for me on your sample data using pandas 0.19.1, I'm running python 3.4 and numpy 1.11.0

Comment: @EdChum Yes, that's what is very strange. It raises the ValueError when I execute it on my DataFrame consisting of 9.000.000 rows but on each subset of 1.000.000 rows of this same DataFrame, it doesn't raise any error.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you use `for key, group in df.groupby(by=['year', 'week', 'city']):` and inside the `for-loop`: `print(key)` and compute `group['avg_rank'].rank(method='first')`? If you still get the ValueError, on which key does the error occur? This might help narrow down the data to the problematic sub-dataset.

Comment: @unutbu No error with the for-loop. Thanks !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since my DataFrame came from several files, I noticed that some indexes were duplicated.

With

```
df.index = np.arange(df.shape[0])
```

just after loading the data, it now works.

Indeed, my hypothesis is that in some groups in the groupby there were sometimes rows with same indexing.

When I tried with subsets of my DataFrame, this case fortunately/unfortunately never happened.

However, the error message is not very exhaustive.

Comment: Thibaut, you saved my girlfriend's day! Now she's not sure whether to be happy because it's finally fixed or mad because she spent hours trying to figure this out when the solution was so simple. Haha!

Can you explain what your code does by the way? Does it simply re-index the data frame?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the data is too large to load in memory, so breaking it up into multiple smaller files makes sense. Can you tell the size of your dataset? Where does the data come from, a csv file or a database? Maybe you should check out blaze: https://github.com/blaze/blaze

Comment: My dataset comes from several csv files totalling 700MB of space. I don't think the data is not able to load in memory since I am running this on a 39 GB RAM machine and it never exceeds 10 GB according to htop. Also, it raises a `ValueError` and not a `MemoryError`.