# Cryptic ValueError in groupby.diff

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm encountering an unhelpful `ValueError` when attempting to do a simple `diff` on a moderately sized dataframe.  I've tracked it down to occuring at a particular line but there's nothing unusual about that line.  (It does correspond to a value where there's only one instance for the `group_by` key, but it's not the only such instance in the data).

```
tp1 = to_predict[['user_id', 'time_period', 'view_count']].head(74105).copy()
tp2 = to_predict[['user_id', 'time_period', 'view_count']].head(74106).copy()

tp1['date_diff'] = tp1.groupby('user_id')['view_count'].diff(1)
tp2['date_diff'] = tp2.groupby('user_id')['view_count'].diff(1)
```

For this snippet, on the last quoted line I get:

```
ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-109-5d39d01dba69> in <module>()
  3 
  4 tp1['date_diff'] = tp1.groupby('user_id')['dates_viewed'].diff(1)
----> 5 tp2['date_diff'] = tp2.groupby('user_id')['dates_viewed'].diff(1)

C:\Users\aleistra-admin\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.pyc in diff(self, periods)
C:\Users\aleistra-admin\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.pyc in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
849                                                             *args, **kwargs)
850                     except (AttributeError):
--> 851                         raise ValueError
852 
853         return wrapper

ValueError:
```

(That's the total error message; nothing further about the ValueError).

If I extract just the few rows around the problematic row and repeat the groupby, it runs without error:

```
tp3 = to_predict[['user_id', 'time_period', 'view_count']][74100:74110].copy()
tp3['date_diff'] =tp3.groupby('user_id')['view_count'].diff(1)
```

Since the problem occurs only in the context of a largish dataframe, I can't provide a meaningful small dataset that reproduces it; as noted, an extract of a few rows does not exhibit the issue.  What's the actual error here, and how do I address it?

Edit: Both 'view_count' and 'time_period' are integers, ranging from 0-30 or so.

As requested in comments:

```
('248560ea75',          user_id  time_period  view_count  date_diff
7261  248560ea75                1             0        NaN
697   248560ea75                0             1        1.0)
('30db47b0e9',          user_id  time_period  view_count  date_diff
7260  30db47b0e9                2             0        NaN
7259  30db47b0e9                1             0        0.0
696   30db47b0e9                0             1        1.0)
('6df3af5d31',          user_id  time_period  view_count date_diff
7258  6df3af5d31                2             0        NaN)
('8434123132',          user_id  time_period  view_count  date_diff
7257  8434123132               11             0        NaN
7256  8434123132               10             0        0.0
7255  8434123132                9             0        0.0
7254  8434123132                2             0        0.0)
```

The problematic row here is the one with user_id 6df3af5d31.  For readability I have truncated the user_id here, they're actually much longer. Again, the row does not cause a problem *in this subsample*, only in the context of the full ~80K row dataframe.

Comment: Can you show us the group that the problematic row gets sorted into in the groupby statement?
`for name, group in tp3.groupby('user_id'):; print(name, group)`

Comment: Edited question to include this

Comment: As you mentioned, this is a bit of a tough problem to debug but let's give it a shot. The only thing I can see stand out about that row is that it is the only row in a group with only one row. Is that true for the entire DataFrame as well? What happens if you add another row with the same user_id to that DataFrame and repeat the groupby and diff on the entire DataFrame - does it work?

Comment: Are there other groups in your entire DataFrame groupby that only contain one row? You should be able to check this by using `tp2.groupby('user_id').filter(lambda x: x.shape[0]==1)`.

Comment: As I remarked in the question, it is not the only case where there's only one row for a user_id (or a group), and I'm able to group over that row in a smaller dataframe.   (Indeed, if I chunk up the dataframe and group over the pieces separately, I can work around the issue entirely).

Comment: Do the other rows in groups with only one row also contain a NaN value?

Comment: The NaN is in the diff column and is due to the only-one-row per group, since what is shown is from the ten-row extract around the problematic row, after successfully doing the diff.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174898/discussion-between-tobsecret-and-a-leistra).

Comment: Possible duplicate of:  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41610667/valueerror-in-rank-method-in-pandas-without-more-explanation

What pandas version and what python version are you using? I take it you are using python 2.x, since your path points to anaconda2?

Comment: This might be a python 2 related bug, so if you can, I would try with a fresh conda environment with python 3 and the latest version of pandas